# Angularjs popover plugin not working correctly

Tags: jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive, popover

I'm novice to angularjs. I've a problem with Popover jquery plugin, I've created a directive for it and don't know why it's not working correctly

here is a plunker [link](http://plnkr.co/edit/paPPjooKV5Cf9is7wOJh?p=preview)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your binding is read without evaluation against the current scope. You could do evaluation manually using scope.$eval.

Try reading the data as text and evaluate manually:

```
var api = scope.$eval($(this).attr('data-api'));
```

[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/oNzi7qAwARweFEyoRMrN?p=preview)

Another solution using `$timeout` to schedule the function to the next phase to ensure that angular has finished its bindings => we don't need to use `scope.$eval` anymore:

```
app.directive('popover', function($timeout) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      $timeout(function(){
          element.popover({
          trigger: 'hover',
          html: true,
          content: function() {
            var api = angular.fromJson(attrs.api);

            return (
              '<ul><li>' + api[0] + ',' + api[1] + '</li><li>' + api[2] + ',' + api[3] + '</li>');
          }
        });
      });
    }
  };
});
```

[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/F8iWqJHRG1KAzoaL2u21?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks, but why the title still have problem?

Comment: @Ahmed Hashem: I added another solution, I think it's better to let angular do the bindings, we avoid doing it ourselves which may conflict with angular bindings and create unpredictable results.